# Configuring Grunt for Jekyll, Haml, Sass on GitHub Pages

Tags: sass, haml, gruntjs, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to run my development/prototyping environment (not a blog) using Jekyll, Haml, Sass and host it on GitHub Pages.

Locally, I use Grunt.js to compile HAML, SASS and serve/build Jekyll.

While my Gruntfile.js is able to do my tasks, it's extremely slow as I try to run the build and serve concurrently.

Any Grunt experts can point me to the right direction on how to optimize my Grunt config so it can run faster? Thanks!

Below is my current config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

jekyll: {
  options: {                          
    src : './',
    dest: './_gh_pages',
    config: '_config.build.yml'       // avoid the relative baseurl issue
  },

  serve: {
    options: {
      serve: true,
      port: 9001
    }
  },

  dev: {

  }
},

compass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      config: 'config.rb',
      force: true
    }
  }
},

haml: {
  includes: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'haml/includes/',
    src: ['*.haml'],
    dest: '_includes/',
    ext: '.html'
  },
  layouts: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'haml/layouts/',
    src: ['*.haml'],
    dest: '_layouts/',
    ext: '.html'
  },
  pages: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'haml/',
    src: ['*.haml'],
    dest: './',
    ext: '.html'
  }
},    

watch: {
  options: {
    atBegin: true
  },
  sass: {
    files: ['sass/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['compass:dev']
  },
  haml: {
    files: ['haml/**/*.haml'],
    tasks: ['haml:includes', 'haml:layouts', 'haml:pages']
  },
  jekyll: {
    files: ['./**/*.html', './**/*.css'],
    tasks: ['jekyll:dev']
  }
},
concurrent: {
  target: {
    tasks: ['jekyll:serve', 'watch'],
    options: {
      logConcurrentOutput: true
    }
  }
}
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-validation');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jekyll');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-haml');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['concurrent:target']);
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get Grunt to work with Jekyll? I haven't gotten around to trying it and I'm just curious what your experiences were.

Comment: Yes, I've been using Grunt to work with Jekyll for a few months already. I think it's great. My only performance issue is with sass and compass.

Answer (score 4):

I haven’t used `Grunt` with `haml` or `jekyll`, but I use it on a daily basis to manage several projects, using different packages as needed.

It’s hard to tell how complex or how big your application is just by looking at your `Gruntfile.js`, but I would definitely start by making tasks a bit smarter. The `watch` task is usually the one I put most attention on, because that’s *preferably* the only task that should run upon saving files. For instance if you save a `.scss` file, only the `compass:dev` task is fired up. If you save a `.js` file, the tasks `jshint`, `jasmine` and `uglify:dev` would fire up. That keeps the development wheel turning only where it’s needed, and `Grunt` completing tasks faster.

Another thing I don’t see in your `Gruntfile.js` is dedicated tasks for `dev` and `dist`, which can be a good practice. An example:

```
// Start web server
grunt.registerTask('serve', [
    'connect:livereload',
    'watch'
]);

// Compile production files
grunt.registerTask('dist', [
    'jshint',
    'jasmine',
    'uglify:dist',
    'compass:dist'
]);

// Compile developer friendly environment
grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'jshint',
    'jasmine',
    'uglify:dev',
    'compass:dev',
    'connect:livereload'
]);

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', 'dev’);
```

Use `$ grunt serve` on one shell to start a local server and watch the app. To make full builds without relying on the `watch` task, run `$ grunt` to make a full `dev` build (because that’s the default task on this example) or run `$ grunt dist` to make a production-ready build.

So my advice is to rely on the `watch` task while developing, and running *do-it-all* tasks sparingly. `Grunt`’s beauty is not only on *multi-tasking*, but also on *tasking-on-demand*. Running full builds on each and every file save is possible, but is not efficient.

BTW, your `jekyll` task within `watch` is empty, because `jekyll:dev` is empty:

```
jekyll: {
    files: ['./**/*.html', './**/*.css'],
    tasks: ['jekyll:dev']
}
```

Hope it helps!